# Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key when switching from native Java to expo

Tags: android, react-native, expo

We are updating our mobile app which was originally developed by another company using native Java / Swift for each platform, but we have decided to switch to React Native with Expo.

When deploying the app build to the play store we get the following error:

"Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key. Ensure that your App Bundle is signed with the correct signing key and try again"

I have seen this answered a lot for native development, but none of the answers quite cover our exact scenario of having switched developers entirely and having completely switch tech stacks.

Does anyone know what would help this app update work?

I have tried making the `com.appname` values match and a few other things to no avail.

Comment: You need to sign your new app with the same signing key as the previous version. Of you don't have it, you need to get it from your previous developers.

Comment: What happens if we can’t get it? Just delete the app and re add it? @AlexanderHoffmann

Comment: You can't update your app without it. You will need to upload your new app with a different applicationId. It will be handled like a different app. You can disable your existing old app but users who have already downloaded it, can continue to use the old version.